# find strings with similar characters in group setting in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

```
> dput(mydf)
structure(list(pID = structure(c(69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 69L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L), .Label = c("S001", "S002", 
"S003", "S004", "S005", "S006", "S007", "S009", "S012", "S013", 
"S014", "S015", "S016", "S017", "S020", "S021", "S022", "S025", 
"S027", "S028", "S029", "S030", "S032", "S035", "S036", "S038", 
"S039", "S040", "S041", "S042", "S043", "S044", "S045", "S047", 
"S048", "S049", "S050", "S051", "S052", "S053", "S056", "S057", 
"S058", "S059", "S060", "S061", "S062", "S063", "S064", "S065", 
"S066", "S067", "S069", "S070", "S071", "S073", "S075", "S076", 
"S077", "S078", "S079", "S080", "S081", "S082", "S083", "S084", 
"S087", "S088", "S089", "S090", "S091", "S093", "S095", "S097", 
"S099", "S100", "S101", "S103", "S104", "S105", "S106", "S107", 
"S109", "S110", "S112", "S113", "S114", "S115", "S116", "S117", 
"S118", "S119", "S121", "S123", "S124", "S125", "S127", "S128", 
"S129", "S130", "S133", "S134", "S135", "S136", "S138", "S139", 
"S141", "S142", "S143", "S144", "S145", "S146", "S149", "S150", 
"S151", "S152", "S153", "S154", "S155", "S156", "S157", "S161", 
"S163", "S164", "S166", "S168", "S170", "S171", "S172", "S176", 
"S177", "S179", "S180", "S182", "S183", "S188", "S189", "S190", 
"S191", "S192", "S195", "S197", "S200", "S201", "S202", "S204", 
"S211", "S214", "S217", "S218", "S220", "S222", "S224", "S229", 
"S231", "S234", "S235", "S238", "S246", "S250", "S251", "S254", 
"S327", "S333", "S338", "S441", "S467", "S486", "S503", "S523", 
"S532"), class = "factor"), tID = structure(c(9L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 
23L, 27L, 28L, 10L, 19L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 23L), .Label = c("", "3T1_1", 
"3T3_1", "3T3_2", "3T4_1", "3T4_2", "T", "T1", "T1_1", "T1_2", 
"T1_3", "T1_4", "T11", "T2", "T2_1", "T2_2", "T3", "T3_1", "T3_2", 
"T4", "T4_1", "T4_2", "T5", "T5_1", "T5_2", "T6", "T8", "T9"), class = "factor"), 
    sID = structure(c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, NA, 
    NA, 27L, 27L, NA, 27L), .Label = c("", "P1", "P10", "P11", 
    "P12", "P13", "P14", "P15", "P16", "P17", "P18", "P19", "P2", 
    "P20", "P21", "P22", "P23", "P24", "P25", "P26", "P27", "P28", 
    "P29", "P3", "P30", "P31", "P32", "P33", "P34", "P35", "P36", 
    "P37", "P38", "P39", "P4", "P40", "P41", "P42", "P43", "P44", 
    "P45", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

In the data frame above I would like to do 2 things;

1. In **sID** col fill the **NA** value with the same string as the rest of the rows in that col based on value in **pID** col. So all **S089** will have P30 in **sID**.
2. Make a new col, group based on **pID** and then mark each row as **unique** if **tID** value before **_** is different otherwise **repeated**. So **S089** will be marked **repeated** for **T1_1**, **T1_2** and **T3_1** and **T3_2** and the rest of the rows will be marked **unique**

Should be possible with dplyer, I guess. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the premises that

- inside each `pID` group the `sID` remains always equal
- if a value in `tID` contains an underscore (`_`) then it's "repeated" (as this is what emerges from your sample data)

one possible solution using `tidyr` and `dplyr` is

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mydf %>% 
  group_by(pID) %>% 
  fill(sID, .direction = "downup") %>% 
  mutate(new_col = ifelse(grepl("_", tID), "repeated", "unique"))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   pID [2]
#    pID   tID   sID   new_col 
#    <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>   
#  1 S089  T1_1  P30   repeated
#  2 S089  T11   P30   unique  
#  3 S089  T2    P30   unique  
#  4 S089  T3_1  P30   repeated
#  5 S089  T5    P30   unique  
#  6 S089  T8    P30   unique  
#  7 S089  T9    P30   unique  
#  8 S089  T1_2  P30   repeated
#  9 S089  T3_2  P30   repeated
# 10 S095  T1    P32   unique  
# 11 S095  T2    P32   unique  
# 12 S095  T3    P32   unique  
# 13 S095  T5    P32   unique
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Wondering if possible to add number to number of time each tID is repeated ?

Comment: It is possible of course, but I believe it should be posted as a different question as it may be searched and be helpful for future users as well :)